# Normal queries to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make an old PHP system working on my new site. However, for it to work, everything has to be using PDO instead of regular MySQL query. I'm just trying to make it work for fun, I'm not an expert at all and just experimenting. However, I can't seem to find a solution for the problem I'm having.

I just keep getting the error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query()

I've marked the lines with // ERROR LINE //

Original code:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$day = $_GET['week'];

if($_GET['week'] == ""){
    $day = date("l");
    $_GET['week'] = date("l");
}

$slot = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rp_timetable WHERE day = '$day'"));

function outit($time, $num){
    global $day, $slot;
    $info = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rp_users WHERE id = '".$slot[$num]."'"));
    if($slot[$num] == ""){ 
        $book[$num] = "OPEN SLOT"; 
    }else{
        $book[$num] = "<b>DJ ".$info['djname']."</b>";
    }
    if($num%2){
        echo "<tr class='colour'><td width='150px' align='center'>$time</td><td width='150px' align='center'>".$book[$num]."<td></tr>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td width='150px' align='center'>$time</td><td width='150px' align='center'>".$book[$num]."<td></tr>";
    }
}

echo "<div id='timetable_pub'><center>";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT sitename FROM rp_data");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<u>".$row['sitename']." Radio Timetable</u><p>";
}
echo "<h1>-You are currently viewing ";
echo "$day";
echo "'s timetable-</h1><p>";
echo "<a href='?week=Monday'>Monday</a> | <a href='?week=Tuesday'>Tuesday</a> | <a href='?week=Wednesday'>Wednesday</a> | <a href='?week=Thursday'>Thursday</a> | 
<a href='?week=Friday'>Friday</a> | 
<a href='?week=Saturday'>Saturday</a> | <a href='?week=Sunday'>Sunday</a><br><hr><br>
<table border='0' valign='middle' align='center'><tr>
<td width='150px' align='center'><u>Time</u></td>
<td width='150px' align='center'><u>DJ Booked</u><td></tr>";

outit('12:00 - 01:00 AM', 1);
$i = 2;
while($i <= 12){
    $start_time = $i - 1;
    $end_time = $i;
    if(strlen($start_time) == 1){$start_time = "0".$start_time;}
    if(strlen($end_time) == 1){$end_time = "0".$end_time;}
    $full_time = "$start_time:00 - $end_time:00 AM";
    outit($full_time, $i);
    $i++;
}
outit('12:00 - 01:00 PM', 13);
$i = 14;
while($i <= 24){
    $start_time = $i - 13;
    $end_time = $i - 12;
    if(strlen($start_time) == 1){$start_time = "0".$start_time;}
    if(strlen($end_time) == 1){$end_time = "0".$end_time;}
    $full_time = "$start_time:00 - $end_time:00 PM";
    outit($full_time, $i);
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>
</center><p></div>";
?>
```

Where I'm currently at (Could be entirely wrong tho):

```
<?php
$day = $_GET['week'];
echo $day;

if($_GET['week'] == ""){
    $day = date("l");
    $_GET['week'] = date("l");
}

// ERROR LINE //
$slotData = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM rp_timetable WHERE day = '$day'");
$slot = $slotData->fetch();

function outit($time, $num){
    global $day, $slot;
    $slotInfo = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM rp_users WHERE id = '".$slot[$num]."'");
    $info = $slotInfo->fetch();
    if($slot[$num] == ""){ 
        $book[$num] = "AutoDJ"; 
    }else{
        $book[$num] = "<b>".$info['djname']."</b>";
    }
    if($num%2){
        echo "<tr class='colour'><td width='150px' align='center'>$time</td><td width='150px' align='center'>".$book[$num]."<td></tr>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td width='150px' align='center'>$time</td><td width='150px' align='center'>".$book[$num]."<td></tr>";
    }
}
// ERROR LINE //
echo "<div id='timetable_pub'><center>";
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT sitename FROM rp_data");
while($row = $result->fetch()) {
echo "<u>".$row['sitename']." Radio Timetable</u><p>";
}
echo "<h1>-You are currently viewing ";
echo "$day";
echo "'s timetable-</h1><p>";
echo "<a href='?week=Monday'>Monday</a> | <a href='?week=Tuesday'>Tuesday</a> | <a href='?week=Wednesday'>Wednesday</a> | <a href='?week=Thursday'>Thursday</a> | 
<a href='?week=Friday'>Friday</a> | 
<a href='?week=Saturday'>Saturday</a> | <a href='?week=Sunday'>Sunday</a><br><hr><br>
<table border='0' valign='middle' align='center'><tr>
<td width='150px' align='center'><u>Time</u></td>
<td width='150px' align='center'><u>DJ Booked</u><td></tr>";

outit('12:00 - 01:00 AM', 1);
$i = 2;
while($i <= 12){
    $start_time = $i - 1;
    $end_time = $i;
    if(strlen($start_time) == 1){$start_time = "0".$start_time;}
    if(strlen($end_time) == 1){$end_time = "0".$end_time;}
    $full_time = "$start_time:00 - $end_time:00 AM";
    outit($full_time, $i);
    $i++;
}
outit('12:00 - 01:00 PM', 13);
$i = 14;
while($i <= 24){
    $start_time = $i - 13;
    $end_time = $i - 12;
    if(strlen($start_time) == 1){$start_time = "0".$start_time;}
    if(strlen($end_time) == 1){$end_time = "0".$end_time;}
    $full_time = "$start_time:00 - $end_time:00 PM";
    outit($full_time, $i);
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>
</center><p></div>";
?>
```

Comment: `$dbh` does not exist within the scope of your `outit` function.

Comment: Where do you ever define `$dbh`?  What do you expect it to be and why?

Comment: @David maybe its in connect.php which is inclided on top

Comment: @anthony_718: Not in the code producing the error it isn't.  And even if it does get included, that still doesn't answer what it is or why it should have a method called `query`.

Answer (score -1):

I have shown a piece of code to connect to database using pdo for php in your case, the $day cannot be directly passed inside the sql query as sql doest not accept that syntax ,hope it helps to understand

```
try {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM rp_timetable WHERE day =?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$day,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $response = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($response);  
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: At least explain what is going on here. Also, why do you have `die` there? It's useless